# Getting Exception when try to get html from UWP WebView (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101)

Tags: javascript, uwp

I need to get html from a WebView. I found the following code on the Internet:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    WebView wb = new WebView();
    wb.Navigate(new Uri(@"https://www.microsoft.com/"));
    Thread.Sleep(1500);
    F(wb);
}
public async void F(WebView webView)
{
    var siteHtML = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
}
```

Unfortunately, the InvokeScriptAsync method returns an error, and I don't understand scripts at all. Do you have any other ways to get html from WebView, or can you fix my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Getting Exception when try to get html from UWP WebView (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101)

The problem is WebView  has not navigation completed, for this scenario, you could call eval function in [`NavigationCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationcompleted?view=winrt-20348) event. During the test it woks well.

```
wb.Navigate(new Uri(@"https://www.microsoft.com/"));
wb.NavigationCompleted += Wb_NavigationCompleted;

.....

private async void Wb_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    var siteHtML = await wb.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
}
```